# Not able to set up Gwibber Online accounts

Tags: proxy, gwibber, online-accounts

I first tried Ubuntu 12.10 from the Live USB and then eith Virtual Box. In both cases I was able to connect to my google Account from Gwibber.

But now I have done a clean install, but am not able to connect at all.

I get a rotating circle, which just keeps on going.

I am using a proxy server whose details I have given in the Network Proxy settings.
I have also set up the http_proxy, https_proxy and ftp_proxy variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went on to enter my proxy details using gconf and dconf editors.

Now I am able to connect to Online accounts.

The funny part is that I didn't do any of this in the LiveUSB, but it worked perfectly there.